# SQL Subqueries Issue

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do an assignment for my course where one of the questions is to get the faculty name, date hired (in dd-mon-yyyy format) and that have the same title as Erit Jackson in the database, who's title is Assoc Prof. My code looks identical to the example provided by the instructor, but when I run this code, I get the error:

## 2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

I don't know what I'm doing wrong thus far?

```
SELECT CONCAT('Dr.', ' ', LName) As 'Faculty Name', DateHired
FROM Faculty
WHERE Title = (
SELECT Title
FROM Faculty
WHERE Title = 'Assoc Prof');
```

Comment: Have you considered looking up that error message in the MySQL docs?

Comment: I have. I don't understand what they're talking about there.

Comment: "I don't understand what they're talking about there." Then *that's* what you should be asking about, @Morgander.  The documentation associates that message with misuse of MySQL's C API.  Supposing it's right (highly likely), the message isn't about your SQL at all, but rather about the *program* by which you are executing it.

Comment: Your SQL itself looks valid (albeit weird, as the answers so far have pointed out).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make a lot of sense as written. It can be simplified:

```
SELECT CONCAT('Dr.', ' ', f1.LName) As 'Faculty Name', f1.DateHired
    FROM Faculty f1
        INNER JOIN Faculty f2
            ON f1.Title = f2.Title
    WHERE f2.FName = 'Erit'
        AND f2.LName = 'Jackson';
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using the subquery is redundant. You're asking the database for the person that has the title(`select` & `from`), that matches(`where title =`) a table of titles with the title of 'Assoc Prof'(`subquery`).

Your professor wants your subquery to find the title of Erit Jackson, not to specifically find the title "Assoc Prof". Do you see the difference? You won't ever have the text "Assoc Prof" in your query at all.